# How do I pass the value to Controller from View without Creating any Object for Model in View in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, asp.net-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4 With Entity Framework. I just want to pass the value from View to Controller, I am unable to get it. Please help me to get it. Thanks in advance.

This is my View code:

```
 <form id="changepassword" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Change", "ChangePassword")">
             <input type="password" value="currentpswd" class="form-control pword" placeholder="Current Password" />
             <input type="password" value="newpswd" class="form-control pword" placeholder="New Password" />
             <input type="password" value="cnfrmpswd"  class="form-control pword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="change">Submit</button>
             </form>



This is my Controller code:

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Change(FormCollection forms)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              string currentpswd=Convert.ToString(forms["currentpswd"]);
                string newpass= (string)forms["newpswd"];
                string confirmpass=forms["cnfrmpswd"];
                Tbl_Users user = new Tbl_Users();
                if (newpass == confirmpass)
                {
                    user.UserPassword = newpass;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "ChangePassword");

        }
```

Comment: What is your problem with receiving objects in the controller actions?

Comment: I have no problem with receiving values in Controller.  I don't have any field like UserPasswordSalt in my Model and database too, I just want to pass the values from without using Model field in View.

Comment: Please share your entire view code and the get and post action results for `ChangePassword` Action.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write any code for this. My problem is passing the value without using the model field in View like u=>u.UserName.

Comment: Start with [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). I hope it helps!

Comment: You should not test modelstate isvalid as form collection is a collection rather than a model.

Answer (score 0):

How about using form collection  You would create an action method that will handle the post when the user clicks the post button:

It will post a collect of the form fields to the controller, you can then reference by using the Name property from the original form fields.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection forms)
{
   var userPassword = (string)forms["UserPassword"];
   var userSalt  = (string)forms["UserSalt"]; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, Still unable to get it.And also i tried another one.   I have updated my code, Please check it out.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you see an error? When you debug what does the form collection hold?